# Autocomplete with jquery and JSON

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm completly new to javaScript and all this stuff.
I need to implement autocomplete so I started with simple example. Here the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: "http://myUrl.com/suggest.json?term=harry",
                  success: function( data ) {
                    response( data.suggestions );
                  }
                });
              },
        });
      });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is json I got from url mentioned in script:

```
{
    "term" : "harry",
    "count" : 4,
    "suggestions" : 
    [
        "harry potter",
        "harry l.",
        "harry a.",
        "harry leon"
    ]
}
```

Seems to be ok but I don't get an autocomplete option. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem source. There were few of them so maybe it will be interesting to others.

First problem is crossdomain call restriction. To allow cross domain calls, callback function must be implemented on returned json.

Second it didn't work in whole project after I made it work as stand alone html. The problem was .menu function overriding in one of my *.jsp files. From googling itm I found solution (not the best I guess but still works) to rename .menu function in jquery.js file. After these manipulations all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. One issue I see is that `},` should be `}` as `},` will not work in IE

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/t6xcG/)**

Comment: it works fine if you define suggestions in same script. But it's not my case